# Setup Ubuntu 18.04 32-BIT?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, lubuntu, budgie

I have Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit in my old laptop and using Lubuntu's desktop environment in it.
And I want to install Ubuntu Budgie in it.

So, i entered

```
tasksel
```

and unchecked all the options and selected ubuntu budgie desktop and pressed ok
then an error came:

`tasksel: apt-get failed (100)`

so I thought it might be not to the internet because it was **running in a CLI version only.**
then i found that all the packages were broken and i couldn't install any packages or rebuild all the packages again.

So i rebooted and tried ubuntu(recovery mode) but it was also a failure.
It didn't show any change in it.

**How can I get my system back?**

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install`? (ie. a `--fix-broken` type action) A few things confuse me, especially "*recovery mode.. also a failure.. didn't show any change*"?  What were you expecting? compared to what did you get? Did you expect a runlevel 1? or what?  Users using `tasksel` usually know their way around terminal so the use of it makes me feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Why not preserve /home and install [Budgie 18.04 32 bit](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads/)?

Comment: in recovery mode i did all the options such as fixing broken packages and all those but it was a failure. means nothing worked